# How to dewinterize a home

Tags: winterizing

What's the best way to dewinterize a home?  What could go wrong if water is just turned back on without doing anything else?

I am in St Louis, MO. The home has been winterized since December.  The weather was pretty cold at a time, but now it's fairly warm.

I read this article and the process seems pretty exhaustive so I just wanted to know if it's really that necessary especially with water heater and such. Is it safe to just make sure all water faucets are on and then turn water back on?  Should electricity to water heater be off?

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/dewinterize-house-88126.html

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing people will need more details before answering, such as your location, climate, concerns, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Griscom.  Updated my question with more details.

Comment: Quick answer: do NOT turn on your water heater until it's full of water!

Comment: Thanks @DanielGriscom.  Any other suggestions?  Just leave all faucets to ON position while water is being turned back on?